# How to compare data arrays correctly with changed variable

Tags: arrays, math, dataset, compare, comparison

I have a data array, let's name it "A" that gets a new datapoint every day. Until now it has 100 datapoints. Tomorrow it will get a new datapoint but 1 controlled variable will change and we will gather 100 more datapoints with the variable changed. I'd like to measure that change, and I have enough sample size in the existing datapoints to measure it with low error margin.

So we have A_benchmark[1...100] and A_modified[1...100] , where the benchmark values are the original 100 datapoints, and the modified one will be the new data gathered with the variable changed.

Now after the new gata is gathered, I'd like to measure the difference, I'd like advice on how should I do this.

1) Should I take the average of the A_benchmark and the average of A_modified, subtract the averages and take the absolute value:

```
Absolute(Average(A_benchmark[1...100])-Average(A_modified[1...100]))
```

2) Should I do the average of (A_benchmark+A_modified), and then subtract the A_modified and then take the absolute value

```
Absolute(Average(A_benchmark[1...100]+A_modified[1...100])-A_modified[1...100])
```

I have a dilemma and I cannot decide which one is the correct one, the argument behind 1 is because the controlled variable is changed so the data arrays have to be isolated. But the logic behind 2 is that the entire data is needed to compare it to the new one.

So how should I do it?

Comment: There are a million ways to do this. It all depends on what you want to do with the result. You could use [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), [PSNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_signal-to-noise_ratio), or any other error measure that fits your scenario.

Comment: I would like to know the raw data or raw result, without any skewing or error correcting.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Have you looked into the two error measures I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, they are not suitable. I should use arithmetic average, because each datapoint has equal weight. The question is which formula.

Comment: E.g. MSE is basically the average of errors. In its basic form, there is usually no weighting involved. Please clarify your requirements and explain why MSE and PSNR do not fulfill these (edit the question to do so).